PostgreSQL: extend table with additional calculated values
as result of complicated select I have the_table with the structure like:
pl_id, date, value

I also have another table (let it calls the_source) where I have a list of all vailable pl_id.
The idea is to extend the_table with values from the_source which doesn't exist.
The problem is that some columns must be defined exactly as expected, another - can be any (let it be 0).
CREATE TABLE the_table (
  "pl_id" INTEGER,
  "date" DATE,
  "value" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO the_table
VALUES
  ('1', '2024-05-01', '10'),
  ('1', '2024-06-01', '11'),
  ('2', '2024-05-01', '12'),
  ('2', '2024-06-01', '13');
  

CREATE TABLE the_source (
  "pl_id" INTEGER,
  "msg" TEXT
 );
 
 INSERT INTO the_source
 VALUES
    ('1', 'aaaaa'),
    ('2', 'bbbbb'),
    ('3', 'ccccc'),
    ('4', 'ddddd');

missed records can be found by select:
select * from the_source
where not exists (
  select
    *
  from the_table
  where the_table.pl_id = the_source.pl_id)

I would like to have the_final table with folling information:
  ('1', '2024-05-01', '10'),
  ('1', '2024-06-01', '11'),
  ('2', '2024-05-01', '12'),
  ('2', '2024-06-01', '13')
  ('3', '2024-05-01', '0'),
  ('3', '2024-06-01', '0'),
  ('4', '2024-05-01', '0'),
  ('4', '2024-06-01', '0');

Is it possible realize by SQL commands?

"The problem is that some columns must be defined exactly as expected" Assumption is ....    Please explain why you think that is true. Also explain why you use the tag [tag:union], that does not become clear after reading your question.

deleted tag. it was used because I am talking about union-ing two tables and that command can be used as solution for the questin. Regarding "the problem" - please see suggested solution. @Belayer understood the problem.

Yes, that is possible, the following shows one approach. (see demo)
with the_dates (adate) as
        (select distinct date
           from the_table
        ) 
   , msg_dates (pl_id,msg, adate) as 
       (select s.pl_id,s.msg, adate
          from the_source s
          cross join the_dates
       )
select m.pl_id, m.adate date, coalesce(t.value,0) value 
  from msg_dates  m
  left join the_table t 
    on (t.pl_id, t.date) = (m.pl_id, m.adate) 
 order by m.pl_id, m.adate;

What it does: 
First it generates a CTE the_dates which extracts each interested data from the_table. It then generate a second CTE msg_dates which combines the interested dates with each entry from the_source. Finally, the main query, joins the second CTE back to the table filling on the missing values.  

NOTE: It is generally considered poor using data types and/or reserved words as column names. Date is a Postgres data type and a SQL Standard reserved word (see documentation), Value is also a SQL Standard reserved word. For demo I changed them to t... respectively.

much appreciated, @Belayer ! Tried to solve the task too complicated.
